# During setup of django with sendgrid getting error 401

Tags: python, django, sendgrid

I have added sendgrid to my django  app 
Followed the simple steps from here  https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-django

generated acount and and copied the api at sengrid site

Added code to my view

```
 sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
            from_email = Email("commerce@gmail.com")
            to_email = Email("lopa@gmail.com")
            subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
            content = Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Python")
            mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
            response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, str(payment.id) + response.status_code + response.body + response.headers)
```

And getting Error

> HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

What could be the problem?

```
> Traceback  Traceback: File
> "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\rent_unit_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
> in get_response
>   132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\rent_unit_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py"
> in _wrapped_view
>   22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\src\payment\views.py" in payment_new
>   251.             response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get()) File
> "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\rent_unit_venv\lib\site-packages\python_http_client\client.py"
> in http_request
>   204.                 return Response(self._make_request(opener, request)) File
> "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\rent_unit_venv\lib\site-packages\python_http_client\client.py"
> in _make_request
>   138.         return opener.open(request) File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib2.py" in open
>   435.             response = meth(req, response) File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib2.py" in http_response
>   548.                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs) File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib2.py" in error
>   473.             return self._call_chain(*args) File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib2.py" in _call_chain
>   407.             result = func(*args) File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib2.py" in http_error_default
>   556.         raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> 
> Exception Type: HTTPError at
> /payment/new/28/http://127.0.0.1:8000/lease/payment_details/28/
> Exception Value: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly what it says; You're not authorized. Most likely you're API key isn't set.

The instructions you added to your question show the `SENDGRID_API_KEY` being added to the Django `settings.py`, while you're code shows you fetching from an environment variable.

### Environment Variable Approach

If you're using the environment variable approach, make sure you've set an environment variable called `SENDGRID_API_KEY`. You can check it it's set by opening a python console and typing:

```
import os
os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
```

If a key isn't printed out, that means it's missing. Each OS has a different way of [setting environment variables permanently](https://www.google.ca/search?q=how%20to%20set%20an%20environment%20variable%20permanently), so I'm not going to list them all out here.

### Settings.py Approach

If you're going with the Django `settings.py` approach, simply replace:

```
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
```

with

```
from django.conf import settings

sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=settings.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
```

### Environment Variable in Settings.py Approach

Finally, since `settings.py` is an executable python file, you can also perform an environment variable import there. This has the benefit of being adjustable from a system level or a Heroku console, but still uses `settings.py`.

```
# inside settings.py
import os    
SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
```

Comment: Thank you @Soviut for most detailed Answer!

Comment: i have also same issue but after performing these action i got HTTP Error 400: Bad Request error

Answer (score 0):

Just update your code to use the one you want if you prefer not to use environment variable or settings

SENDGRID_API_KEY = '***sendgrid***api***'

sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=SENDGRID_API_KEY )

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same error, I use this cli to solve: e.g(my_api_key)
 set SENDGRID_API_KEY=SG.FHWXmV68Td2cEYJQrPjDdQ.I1VEkE2CBg7--r7QfS-AzhfSU5
( !!! do not use  ' ' like : 'SG.FHWXmV68Td2cEYJQrPjDdQ.I1VEkE2CBg7--r7QfS-AzhfSU5' ).
also. 
Do not replace SENDGRID_API_KEY line with your API_KEY : 
 sg =SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
. And you should refer this document : 
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python
 I think this problem is because the window user,see this and you will understand . Acc to this doc : 
[image: instruction_from_git]